# Does ag-grid expose the div row element to consumers?

Tags: html, angular, ag-grid

I was trying to add my own custom directives to the div rows created by ag-grid.

As investigated, each ag-grid row will made up of a div element level. I need to get access to that div element level.

For example each div element row will contain,

```
<div role="row" row-index="10" row-id="8" comp-id="35" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-even ag-row-animation ag-row-level-2">
```

Does ag-grid expose this div row element to consumers? Or can I use Angular to retrieve those elements?